# VBA to dynamically find a Named Column and then populating with text once found

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Named Table and I am trying to dynamically find the Column named "Quarters" and then add 1, 2, 3, 4 down the column in a repeating manner until the last row is found.

That is, the end result should look like this:

```
Quarter
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
.....
```

I have pulled some code together as below and can find (dynamically) the Column "Quarter" but then I am not sure how to then populate the column from there.  Well, what I try results in an error.  I know this must be simple.  Any suggestions?

```
Sub Add_Quarters_Dynamic_Code()

Dim TargetColumn As Range
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim rngAddress As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Integer

Sheets(1).Select
FinalRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set rngAddress = Range("A:Z").Find("Quarter")
Set TargetColumn = 'So this is where I get lost....

For i = 2 To FinalRow Step 4
    Cells(i, TargetColumn).Resize(, 1).Value = 1
Next i

For j = 3 To FinalRow Step 4
    Cells(j, TargetColumn).Resize(, 1).Value = 2
Next j

For k = 4 To FinalRow Step 4
    Cells(k, TargetColumn).Resize(, 1).Value = 3
Next k

For l = 5 To FinalRow Step 4
    Cells(l, TargetColumn).Resize(, 1).Value = 4
Next l

End Sub
```

Comment: you error is `TargetColumn` needs to be a number, representing the column number, and not `Range`. Change that line to `TargetColumn = rngAddress.Column` (don't forget to define `Dim TargetColumn As Long`)

Comment: Thanks for the code!  I Dim'd TargetColumn As Long and then corrected the line to read "TargetColumn = rngAddress.Column" or even "Set TargetColumn = rngAddress.Column".  Both ways I get either a run time error or a compile error.

Comment: try my code in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code (as comments)

```
Sub Add_Quarters_Dynamic_Code()

Dim TargetColumn As Long
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim rngAddress As Range
Dim i As Long

With Sheets(1)
    ' find last row with data at COlumn A (with skipping blank cells in the middle)
    FinalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' this is searching only in Column A to Z
    Set rngAddress = .Range("A:Z").Find("Quarter")

    ' verify a successful Find
    If Not rngAddress Is Nothing Then
        TargetColumn = rngAddress.Column ' <-- Get column Number

        ' loop only once
        For i = 2 To FinalRow
             .Cells(i, TargetColumn).Value = ((i - 2) Mod 4) + 1
        Next i
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Almost!  It seems to add a 1 to the Column header as the first row of data starts at 2 (and I need it to start at 1).  I think it needs an offset?

Comment: Thank-you!  Works as wanted.  Thanks for calling out the code.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you have a named table. If this is an Excel Table, then you can also use the listObject object and get the column named Quarter.

```
Public Sub fillQuarterColumn()

  Dim quarter As ListColumn
  'need error handling here in case table name or column name have changed
  Set quarter = Sheet2.ListObjects("myTable").ListColumns.Item("Quarter")

  Dim cell As Range
  Dim count As Long

  For Each cell In quarter.DataBodyRange
        cell.Value = (count Mod 4) + 1
        count = count + 1
  Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: It never sits right when I see "cell" used as a variable name for a range. I'm gonna see if there's any documentation that discusses this point

Answer (score 0):

I used a combo of some of the answers, this will probably give some error like you do not have enough resources to do this because it will go to the very last row. But what ever you set FinalRow to it will go to there.

```
Sub Add_Quarters_Dynamic_Code()
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim rngAddress As Integer
Sheets(1).Select
FinalRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).Row
rngAddress = Range("A:Z").Find("Quarter").Column
Cells(2, rngAddress).Value = "=MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,4)+1"
Cells(2, rngAddress).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, rngAddress), Cells(FinalRow, rngAddress)), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

a quite short code:

```
With Sheets(1)
    Intersect(.Range("A:Z").Find("Quarter").EntireColumn, .UsedRange.Offset(1).Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.count - 1)).Formula = "=MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,4)+1"
End With
```

Comment: would the brave downvoter ever care to explain the reason why he downvoted so as to have both me enhance my answer and people seeing it learn what he has to teach them?